# How do I get my reducer to update with a form button?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form in TableNumberOne component. When renderButton is clicked, it should trigger an action (addNum) that will add 1 to the checkReducer array.
When I click renderButton, 1 is added only to the tableNumReducer. tableNumReducer should check the action.type of addNum and add the action.payload to checkReducer, but its not. How do I get 1 added to checkReducer when clicking renderButton based on the action.type of addNum?

Here is a link to my code repository:

https://github.com/Jsparks1989/table-number-form/blob/master/table/src/components/TableNumberOne.js

Here is a screenshot of my console.log after I click renderButton:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `<button onClick={()=>this.props.addNum(1)} >1</button>`